# How to display Grand total and Total of column in PageblockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com

I want to display Grand Total Amount and Total Amount(Particular Column total) but its not working.

Please help me to achieve this.
1)Here Grand total is total of Amount__c in Expensive__c object and
2)Total Amount is Particular Column total displayed in pageblocktable, in below image you can see its only showing Total amount is 56.

[image]

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="ExpensesClass" >

<apex:form >
<!-- Need this variables for totals generation -->
<apex:variable value="{!0}" var="total1"/>

<apex:pageBlock >

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!expensesList}" var="e" rendered="{!isTableExit}" >

<apex:column value="{!e.Date__c}"/>
<!--<apex:column value="{!e.Item__c}"/>-->
<apex:column >
<apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="/{!e.id}">{!e.Item__c}</apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>

<apex:column headerValue="Amount">
<apex:outputField value="{!e.Amount__c}" />
<apex:variable var="total1" value="{!e.Amount__c}" />
<apex:facet name="footer">
               Total: <span class="t1"></span>   
</apex:facet>
</apex:column>

</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockSection >
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel value="Grand Total Amount:"/>
<apex:outputText value="{!totalsum1}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
<script>
// Here we will set the generated subtotals to the footer cells

document.getElementsByClassName('t1')[0].innerHTML = '{!total1}'; 
</script>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Class:**

```
public class ExpensesClass {
public string nameQuery{get;set;}
public List<Expense__c> expensesList{get;set;}
public Boolean isTableExit {get;set;}
public Date fromdate {get; set;}
public Date todate {get; set;}
public list<AggregateResult> totalsum {get;set;}
public integer totalsum1{get;set;}

//public List<Expense__c> expensesList {get; set;}
public ExpensesClass(){
totalsize=[Select count() From Expense__c];
totalsum=new list<AggregateResult>();
//totalsum=[Select sum(Amount__c) From Expense__c];
}

public PageReference executeSearch(){
string str='%'+nameQuery+'%';
if(nameQuery==null || nameQuery==''){
    //errormessage ='Name cannot be null or empty. Please Try Again.';
    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please Enter Owner Name'));
}else{
expensesList=[Select id, Item__c, owner.name,Amount__c, Date__c From Expense__c where owner.name LIKE:str Limit:limitsize Offset:offsetsize];
}

return null;
}

public Void gettotalsum1(){
AggregateResult[] groupedresult=[Select sum(Amount__c) From Expense__c];
object totalsum1=groupedresult[0].get('total');
//return totalsum;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance 
Shaik

Answer (score 4):

Completely in the context in what you posted / are asking, you are not adding the values which is why it only shows the last value....

You need to:

```
<apex:variable var="total1" value="{!e.Amount__c + total1}" />
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, now column total working fine. how to display grand total.

Comment: @Shaik - Please mark as accepted answer then so others looking for similar questions can find ones with an answer